# Angular - Singleton Service Changes only getting to one component

Tags: angular

I have several components that I want to adjust to a changing set of variables. I display the value of that boolean in each component where it needs to change. However, when I click an icon to flip a setting from true to false, that change is reflected in only the component where the click took place.

Here is the component structure. They all need access to the data

main
bench
 |
 --- dimensions
 --- headers
 --- logo

main Component - Similar technique used in all components.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { DesignStudioService } from 'app/main/design-studio/design-studio.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'design-main-selector',
  templateUrl: './main.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./main.component.scss'],
  providers:  [ DesignStudioService ]
})
export class MainComponent implements OnInit {

    showDimensions : boolean;
    designType : string = 'bench';

    constructor(private _studio: DesignStudioService) { }


    ngOnInit() {
        this._studio
        .currentDim
        .subscribe(showDimensions => this.showDimensions = showDimensions);
    }

    menuClick(param): void {
        this._studio.onMenuClick(param);
    }

    menuLeave(): void {
        this._studio.onMenuLeave();
    }

    menuEnter(param): void {
        this._studio.onMenuEnter(param);
    }

}
```

html for the "main" component. The hexagon is to be clicked and this menuClick function in the component then changes the service, which changes the appearance of the other components. This works in this component, but not the others.

```
<div class="hexagon" 
     style="position:absolute; left:60px; top:8px;" 
     (click)="menuClick('Dimensions')" 
     (mouseleave)="menuLeave()"
     (mouseenter)="menuEnter('Dimensions')">

    <span>  
        <mat-icon style="position:relative; left:15px; top:-5px" 
                  class="w-30 text-center mat-display-1">build
        </mat-icon>
    </span>

</div>
```

dimensions component - not responding to change

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { DesignStudioService } from 'app/main/design-studio/design-studio.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'bench-dimensions',
  templateUrl: './dimensions.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dimensions.component.scss'],
  providers:  [ DesignStudioService ]
})
export class BenchDimensionsComponent implements OnInit {


    showDimensions : boolean;
    designType : string = 'bench';


    constructor(private _studio: DesignStudioService) { }


    ngOnInit() {
        this._studio
        .currentDim
        .subscribe(showDimensions => this.showDimensions = showDimensions);
    }

}
```

Dimensions html (not working)

```
<div>The showDimensions in dimensions is {{showDimensions}}</div>
```

The service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ActivatedRouteSnapshot, Resolve, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { BehaviorSubject, Subject, Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class DesignStudioService implements Resolve<any>
{

    private dimSource = new BehaviorSubject(true);
    currentDim = this.dimSource.asObservable();

    private wallLength = new BehaviorSubject(50);
    sharedWallLength = this.wallLength.asObservable();

    private wallHeight = new BehaviorSubject(50);
    sharedWallHeight = this.wallHeight.asObservable();

    private designType = new BehaviorSubject('bench');
    sharedDesignType = this.designType.asObservable();


    design: any;
    onDesignChanged: BehaviorSubject<any>;



    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param {HttpClient} _httpClient
     */
    constructor(
        private _httpClient: HttpClient
    )
    {
        // Set the defaults
        this.onDesignChanged = new BehaviorSubject({});
    }
```

Comment: It is not a singleton if you add the service to the component providers

Comment: As @KurtHamilton said: Just delete the line "providers:  [ DesignStudioService ]" at the component level and it should work just fine. The Annotation @Injectable({providedIn: 'root'}) registers a global singleton and you weill get the same instance if you inject it in your components.

Comment: adding  DesignStudioService in the module provider array will available to all component of that module

Comment: OK. Thanks. Didn't realize that I had left that in. This fixed it. Really appreciate it guys.